# Hall's Marriage Theorem for defining a winner

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Two teams are competing against each other to secure more deals with shops. Team members are labelled from $\alpha$ to $\iota$ for one team and from a to i for the other. The following sets indicate which shops, labelled from A to I and 1 to 9, are interested in forming deals with members from each team:

$A:\{\delta,\epsilon\}$, $B:\{\delta,\epsilon,\iota\}$, $C:\{\alpha,\beta,\zeta,\eta,\theta\}$, $D:\{\beta,\iota\}$, $E:\{\delta,\iota\}$, $F:\{\gamma,\zeta,\theta,\iota\}$, $G:\{\beta,\delta,\iota\}$, $H:\{\delta,\epsilon\}$, $I:\{\alpha,\gamma,\eta,\theta,\iota\}$

$1:\{a,b,c\}$, $2:\{a,d,f\}$, $3:\{a,b,c,h,i\}$, $4:\{b,c,d,e,h,i\}$, $5:\{a,d,f\}$, $6:\{d,f,g\}$, $7:\{a,d,g\}$, $8:\{d,f,g\}$, $9:\{e,g,h,i\}$

Which team will win and why?

**My assumption** for solving this problem is to use Hall's Marriage Theorem and choose overlapping sets: for example let $S = \{A,G,B,H,E\}$ and its image $N(S)=\{\delta,\epsilon,\iota,\beta\}$, with cardinality 4 and 5 respectively, therefore due to MH theorem matching doesn't exist. Similarly for a second team: $S = \{6,2,8,5\}$ and $N(S) = \{a,d,f,g\}$, and their cardinalities are equal, so is the second team the only possible winner?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).